# Iterating through set in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I am using gdb in interactive mode. At the breakpoint I have a set through which I wish to iterate. I wish to do something like this :

For the set S, I wish to call 'name' method on each element of set and print it.

```
for ( auto s : S ) :
 p s.name()
end
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: The output of `p S` is not enough for you?

Comment: no. It won't print information deeper in the element s.

Comment: With python, you could use the [pretty printing API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing-API.html) to iterate through the set (e.g. `gdb.default_visualizer(gdb.parse_and_eval('S')).children()`).